# How to configure Ubuntu to use all nameservers detected by dnsmasq?

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq, resolvconf

I am having trouble resolving DNS names on an internal VPN network, even though dnsmasq successfully detects nameservers on the VPN. The following is relevant output from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman NetworkManager[840]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman NetworkManager[840]: <warn> dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman NetworkManager[840]: <error> [1413241678.445577] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:396] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman NetworkManager[840]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: started, version 2.68 cache disabled
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:58 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: warning: no upstream servers configured
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:59 snowman NetworkManager[840]: <warn> dnsmasq appeared on DBus: :1.13
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:59 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: setting upstream servers from DBus
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:59 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:59 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: using nameserver 10.1.90.6#53
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 13 19:07:59 snowman dnsmasq[1052]: using nameserver 10.4.4.9#53
```

Evidently, dnsmasq was able to correctly automatically detect all upstream nameservers for my connection. However, my system is somehow unable to query all systems for DNS resolutions.

```
ping: unknown host source
```

Relevant `nslookup` output:

```
> server
Default server: 127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53
> source
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find source: NXDOMAIN
> server 10.1.90.6
Default server: 10.1.90.6
Address: 10.1.90.6#53
> source
Server:     10.1.90.6
Address:    10.1.90.6#53

Name:   source.<REDACTED>
Address: 10.4.4.44
```

Here's the full dnsmasq command run on my system:

```
1052 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to copy the dnsmasq conf file from `/usr/share/doc/dnsmasq-base/examples/dnsmasq.conf.example` to `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf`, enable `strict-order` so that it hits all nameservers, followed by `sudo restart network-manager` to restart the dnsmasq service.

I don't think the default behaviour with `strict-order` disabled is correct. Think I'll file a bug on Launchpad...